# dynamically load PHP code from external file

Tags: php, include

Code is in a static class in an external file eg. /home/test/public_html/fg2/templatecode/RecordMOD/photoslide.mod

How do I load this into my script on demand, and be able to call its functions?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the included code is wrapped in PHP blocks, you can use `include` or `require` for this.

Like so:

`include( '/home/test/public_html/fg2/templatecode/RecordMOD/photoslide.mod' );`

You can then do whatever you wish, call functions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To use the variables or classes (static or otherwise) they need to be loaded before being used. Typically you would make a call like:

```
<?php
require('/home/test/public_html/fg2/templatecode/RecordMOD/photoslide.mod');
?>
```

You can also do without the parentheses:

```
<?php
require '/home/test/public_html/fg2/templatecode/RecordMOD/photoslide.mod';
?>
```

...somewhere at the top of your code.

It would be good to review [`include()`](http://php.net/include), [`require()`](http://php.net/require), [`include_once()`](http://php.net/include_once), and [`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once)

Answer (score 0):

Might be too advanced right now, but PHP supports an autoloader. You would still use the include/require code that is mentioned above. But instead that code would live inside a special  function that will be called anytime you access a class/interface that hasn't already been loaded. This will allow you to see what is being requested and dynamically load files on demand.

Including/requiring a few files is fine. Once you get into a large site with tons of files it will be easier to use the autoloader then explicitly writing an include/require line for each. Plus you will save memory by not loading things you aren't using.

[Autoloader Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), thats the easy version. The better implimentation is with [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).